# maxAllowedContentLength & maxRequestLength Set For Maximum, Security Loophole?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I have a webapp (MVC 4) that it purpose is to do manipulation of files, the way it works is :

User upload file - > the site does manipulation on the file -> the user download the file again (the new version of the file).

So I need to accept a large files size in my site, so what i did :

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />-->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

As you can see I enlarged the "maxAllowedContectLength" and the "maxRequestLength" and "executionTimeout" values.

**My question :**

Does my action create a loophole in the security of my site ?

And if it does, why ? there is a better way to do it ? and what can i do to minimizes the threat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't create a *security* loophole, but it does make it easier for an attacker to flood your server with heavy requests. If `maxAllowedRequest`/`ContentLength` is set to a smaller value, the attacker would have to make more requests in order to flood the server and it may be easier for the server to detect/reject/handle these smaller requests.

`ExecutionTimeout` being high will tie up resources which could otherwise be used to serve other users on your website.

Is there a better way to do it? Yes, use an external service to upload large files. Google Drive/Dropbox/etc. Offload the heavy processing to a purpose-built service. Consider using a cloud service like Amazon/Azure if you want to handle this yourself instead of offloading to a third party. The trick is to move this out of your main web app.

Comment: My web application is on the azure with a SQL DB and every thing is place on the azure cloud.

What you mean by "consider using a cloud service like azure if.."
What can i do ? how can I use Azure services to help me with this? this settings that are set in my application, how can it be in another way?

Comment: @Ron Awesome! For Azure, you'll want to create a new Storage account and store your uploads using the [Blob Service REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx). It may seem like a bit of extra effort, but will dramatically improve the scalability of your application

Comment: @RGaham so let me understand if I get you correctly, I need to:
1) Return to the default settings in my "Web.Config".
2) Change my way(the webapp way) of getting files from the user :
instead of getting the files in the normal way (upload to the server where the website is) i need to send the files to my blob storage)

3.implement a blob storage on my server(virtual machine) that will hold all the files.

bottom line:
the web app will not deal with the files but send them to the blob service API that will take care of it ?

Comment: @Ron Exactly. The Blob service is designed to handle large files. Web applications, generally, are designed to serve short-lived requests

Comment: @RGaham Do i need to transfer the files(blob) directly to the Blob Storage(via JavaScript and etc') or I could upload them in chunks to the server side and from there transfer them to the Blob Storage ?
What you suggest ?

Comment: Directly to the blob storage is best. Otherwise you run into the same problem of overhead on the web server side

Comment: @RGaham Thanks a lot, I'm still trying to figure how can I transfer the data from the client(AJAX) to the blob storage, if you have any reference or code sample ill be very happy :)
Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 1):

This threshold is for securing your site against DOS attack (denial of service attack) - i.e. imagine some reasonable number of hackers sending humongous (in size) requests to your site - your regular users won't be able to use it. In the terms of ASP.NET limit the generous thresholds only to pages that actually do the heavy lifting.

```
<location path="UploadFile.aspx">
  <system.web>
   ...
  </system.web>
</location>
```

In general terms consider some cloud service to do the heavy lifting for you (as RGraham suggested).